# Как правильно сформировать представления на основании некоторых условий?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, инспекция-кода

```
public class DocumentDetails
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int TypeId {get;set;}
    //Прочие свойства
}
public class AddDocumentItem
{
    public int DocumentId {get;set;}
    public int MaterialAssetId {get;set;}
    public decimal Amount {get;set;}
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
}
```

Выше описанные классы используются в качестве моделей для строго типизированных частичных представлений.

Мне необходимо в зависимости от типа документа(`TypeId`) отображать/прятать поле для ввода цены.

Мне приходит в голову 2 возможных варианта реализации данного требования:

1. Создать 2 частичных представления и в главном представлении анализировать тип документа и *рендерить* необходимое, т.е. что то типа `@if(Model.TypeId==условие){@Html.Partial("Первое представление")}else{@Html.Partial("Второе представление")}`
2. В класс модели `AddDocumentItem` добавить поле `DocumentTypeId` в частичное представление добавить условие проверки по данному полю(`@if(Model.DocumentTypeId==условие){}`)
   2.1. Значение типа документа записать в ViewBag.DocumentTypeId которое будет анализироваться в частичном представлении

Но мне кажется что оба варианта как то не совсем в духе MVC: в обоих случаях в представлении присутствует некая логика(какое частичное представление необходимо отобразить;отображать или нет поле для ввода).

Я склоняюсь больше ко второму варианту так как в этом случае будет только **1** а не **2** частичных представления(т.е. как минимум не будет дублирования), но мне не нравится что в этом случае придется в модель *протаскивать* тип документа.

Может есть другие способы решения озвученной мной проблемы, какие то устоявшиеся практики/рекомендации?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо отказаться от термина "модель" и обозвать эти классы словом "DTO" (Data Transfer Object", объект для передачи данных). Потому что, в отличии от моделей - локальные DTO можно изменять произвольно.

После этого вопрос выбора варианта отпадет сам собой.

---

Если же хочется красоты и универсальности - можно к модели "прикреплять" метамодель, описывающую какие именно поля подлежат выводу:

```
public class AddDocumentItem
{
    public DocumentTypeInfo TypeInfo {get;set;}

    public int DocumentId {get;set;}
    public int MaterialAssetId {get;set;}
    public decimal Amount {get;set;}
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
}

public class DocumentTypeInfo 
{
    public bool HasPrice {get;set;}
}
```

Это позволит вынести из вида логику определения состава полей документа - но оставит в самом виде логику их скрытия/показа.

---

В любом случае, разбивать из-за 1 поля вид на два разных - плохая идея, ведь придется либо дублировать всю верстку - либо создавать еще 100500 частичных представлений для общих элементов.